# How to Play song in Albums Tab?

Tags: android, android-adapter, android-music-player

I cant able to play songs in Albums Tab. But song is playing well in All Songs Tab..Even Not showing an error or warning when i run the app..
This is my AlbumFragment

```
 public class AlbumsFragment extends MusicServiceFragment {
private final String TAG="AlbumsFragment";
private MusicService musicService;
private boolean musicServiceStatus = false;
private List<AlbumModel> albums;
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private AlbumAdapter adapter;


@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_albums, container, false);
    recyclerView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.rv_album_list);
    albums = new ArrayList<>();
    adapter = new AlbumAdapter(albums, getContext());
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getContext(), 2);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    if (musicServiceStatus) { initFragment(); }
    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onServiceConnected(MusicService musicService) {
    this.musicService = musicService;
    musicServiceStatus=true;
    initFragment();
}

@Override
public void onServiceDisconnected() {

}

public void initFragment() {
    albums = musicService.getAlbums();
    adapter = new AlbumAdapter(albums, getContext());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    handleAllListener();
}

public void handleAllListener() {
    adapter.setAlbumClickListener((v, album, pos) -> Log.d(TAG, album.getArtistName()));
}

}
```

This is Album Adapter ..No Errors or warning..If you could help in this am very thankful to you..Playing well if is select all songs tab but when i move to albums tab and click song its not playing but getting songs without error

```
  public class AlbumAdapter extends       RecyclerView.Adapter<AlbumAdapter.ViewHolder> {
private List<AlbumModel> albums;
Context context;
private AlbumClickListener albumClickListener;

AlbumAdapter(List<AlbumModel> albums, Context context) {
    this.albums = albums;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_album,parent,false);
    return new ViewHolder(v);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    final AlbumModel albumModel = albums.get(position);
    holder.albumName.setText(albumModel.getName());
    holder.albumNoOfSong.setText(albumModel.getNoOfSong()+ " songs");
    Picasso.with(context).load(albumModel.getCoverArt()).placeholder(R.drawable.default_album_icon).into(holder.albumImage);
    holder.cardView.setOnClickListener(view -> albumClickListener.OnAlbumClickListener(view,albums.get(position),position));

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return albums.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    ImageView albumImage;
    TextView albumName;
    TextView albumNoOfSong;
    CardView cardView;

    ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        albumImage = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.iv_album_image);
        albumName = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_album_name);
        albumNoOfSong=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_album_no_of_song);
        cardView = (CardView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.cv_item_album);
    }
}
public interface AlbumClickListener {
    void OnAlbumClickListener(View v, AlbumModel album, int pos);
}
void setAlbumClickListener(AlbumClickListener albumClickListener) {
    this.albumClickListener = albumClickListener;
     }
 }
```

This is Album Model Class..

```
 public class AlbumModel {
private final ArrayList<SongModel> songs;
public int id;

AlbumModel(ArrayList<SongModel> songs) {
    this.songs = songs;
}
public void setId(int i) {
    this.id=i;
}
public ArrayList<SongModel> getAlbumSongs() {
    return songs;
}

public  String getName() {
    if(songs.size()>0) {
        return songs.get(0).getAlbumName();
    }else {
        return " ";
    }
}
int getNoOfSong() {
    return songs.size();
}

String getCoverArt() {
    if(songs.size()>0) {
        return songs.get(0).getAlbumArt();
    }else {
        return " ";
    }
}

int getArtistId() {
    if(songs.size()>0) {
        return songs.get(0).getArtistId();
    }else {
        return 0;
    }
}
public String getArtistName() {
 if(songs.size()>0) {
        return songs.get(0).getArtistName();
    }else {
        return "";
       }
     }
 }
```

**SongFragment...**

```
 public class SongFragment extends MusicServiceFragment {

public static final String TAG="SongListFragment";

RecyclerView recyclerView;
List<SongModel> songs;
SongAdapter adapter;
private MusicService musicSrv;
boolean musicServiceStatus = false;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_song, container, false);
    songs=new ArrayList<>();
    recyclerView=rootview.findViewById(R.id.rv_song_list);
    adapter=new SongAdapter(songs,getContext());
    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    if(musicServiceStatus) {
        initFragment();
    }
    return rootview;
}

@Override
public void onServiceConnected(MusicService musicService) {
    musicSrv = musicService;
    musicServiceStatus=true;
    initFragment();
}

@Override
public void onServiceDisconnected() {

}

public void handleSongClick() {

    //click on song item title and artist name listener
    adapter.setOnSongItemClickListener((v, song, pos) -> {
        Log.d(TAG,song.getTitle());
        playSong(song);
    });

    // long click on song title and artist listener
    adapter.setOnSongItemLongClickListener((v, song, pos) -> Log.d(TAG,"onsongitemclick listener testing"));

    // song menu click listener
    adapter.setOnSongBtnClickListener((btn, v, song, pos) -> {
        final PopupMenu popupMenu=new PopupMenu(getContext(),btn);
        popupMenu.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.song_action_menu,popupMenu.getMenu());
        popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(item -> {
            if(item.getTitle().equals("Play")) {
                playSong(song);
            }
            return false;
        });
        popupMenu.show();
    });
}

//initialize all the component
public void initFragment() {
    songs=musicSrv.getSongs();
    Log.d(TAG,songs.get(0).getTitle());
    adapter=new SongAdapter(songs,getContext());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    handleSongClick();
}

//make some changes while playing the songs
public void playSong(SongModel song) {
    musicSrv.play(song);
}
```

}

Comment: Look at what you have done differently in `Albums` vs `All`. Provide All Songs adapter

Comment: i looked out All adapters too ..Nothing much different

Comment: You will not be able to get help with the information you have provided. I can see you call a interface `AlbumClickListener` when your holder is selected but you don't show how you handle the the play of the media. You call `OnAlbumClickListener(View v, AlbumModel album, int pos);` but where do you actually handle it?

Comment: All you do is log the the artist name - `Log.d(TAG, album.getArtistName()`

Comment: i have updated with my song adapter .. i tried with log but unsuccesful

Comment: What will be the issue

Comment: All I see is you call your method in your custom interface `OnAlbumClickListener`, same in your `SongAdapter` you call `songItemClickListener`. But you don't show how you handle the play of the song. Can you please provide how you play the song for example - `mMediaPlayer.start();`

Comment: Or at least provide your SongsFragment

Comment: am handling with my musicservice class

Comment: updated with song fragment

Comment: See my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After seeing your `SongFragment` I am able to provide a answer.

In your `AlbumsFragment` you have a `handleAllListener` but you never call your `MusicService`. Try changing your `AlbumsFragment` to this:

```
public class AlbumsFragment extends MusicServiceFragment {
private final String TAG="AlbumsFragment";
private MusicService musicService;
private boolean musicServiceStatus = false;
private List<AlbumModel> albums;
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private AlbumAdapter adapter;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_albums, container, false);
        recyclerView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.rv_album_list);
        albums = new ArrayList<>();
        adapter = new AlbumAdapter(albums, getContext());
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getContext(), 2);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        if (musicServiceStatus) { initFragment(); }
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(MusicService musicService) {
        this.musicService = musicService;
        musicServiceStatus=true;
        initFragment();
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected() {

    }

    public void initFragment() {
        albums = musicService.getAlbums();
        adapter = new AlbumAdapter(albums, getContext());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        handleAllListener();
    }

    public void handleAllListener() {
        adapter.setAlbumClickListener((v, album, pos) -> Log.d(TAG, album.getArtistName()));
    }

    public void handleAlbumClick() {
        //click on song item title and artist name listener
        adapter.setOnAlbumItemClickListener((v, song, pos) {
        Log.d(TAG,song.getTitle());
        playSong(song);
    });

    // song menu click listener
    adapter.setOnAlbumBtnClickListener((btn, v, song, pos) {
        final PopupMenu popupMenu=new PopupMenu(getContext(),btn);
        popupMenu.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.song_action_menu,popupMenu.getMenu());
        popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(item) {
            if(item.getTitle().equals("Play")) {
                playSong(song);
            }
            return false;
            });
            popupMenu.show();
        });
    }

    //make some changes while playing the songs
    public void playSong(AlbumModel song) {
        musicService(song);
    }


}
```

After doing this, you can now call the `OnClickListener` the same way as you did in you `SongAdapter`.

I can edit your `AlbumAdapter` for you, if you provide your `SongAdapter`.

---

Edit: After providing SongAdapter.

You can change your `AlbumAdapter` to this:

```
public class AlbumAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AlbumAdapter.ViewHolder> {
private List<AlbumModel> albums;
Context context;

private AlbumClickListener albumClickListener;
private AlbumItemLongClickListener albumItemLongClickListener;
private AlbumBtnClickListener albumBtnClickListener;

AlbumAdapter(List<AlbumModel> albums, Context context) {
    this.albums = albums;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_album, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(v);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    final AlbumModel albumModel = albums.get(position);
    holder.albumName.setText(albumModel.getName());
    holder.albumNoOfSong.setText(albumModel.getNoOfSong() + " songs");

    if (albumModel.getAlbumArt() != "") {
        Picasso.with(context).load(albumModel.getCoverArt()).placeholder(R.drawable.default_album_icon).into(holder.albumImage);
    }
    holder.constraintLayout.setOnClickListener(view -> {
        if (albumItemClickListener != null) {
            albumItemClickListener.onAlbumItemClick(view, album, position);
        }
    });

    holder.constraintLayout.setOnLongClickListener(view -> {
        if (albumItemLongClickListener != null) {
            albumItemLongClickListener.onAlbumItemLongClickListener(view, album, position);
        }
        return true;
    });

    holder.albumMenuBtn.setOnClickListener(view -> {
        if (albumBtnClickListener != null) {
            albumBtnClickListener.onAlbumBtnClickListener(holder.albumMenuBtn, view, album, position);
        }
    });


}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return albums.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    ImageView albumImage;
    TextView albumName;
    TextView albumNoOfSong;
    CardView cardView;

    ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        albumImage = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.iv_album_image);
        albumName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_album_name);
        albumNoOfSong = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_album_no_of_song);
        cardView = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cv_item_album);
    }
}


    // Custom Interfaces and its method implementations
    public interface AlbumClickListener {
        void onAlbumItemClick(View v, AlbumModel album, int pos);
    }

    public interface AlbumItemLongClickListener {
        void onAlbumItemLongClickListener(View v, AlbumModel album, int pos);
    }

    public interface AlbumBtnClickListener {
        void onAlbumBtnClickListener(ImageButton btn, View v, AlbumModel album, int pos);
    }

    public void setOnAlbumItemClickListener(AlbumItemClickListener albumItemClickListener) {
        this.albumItemClickListener = albumItemClickListener;
    }

    public void setOnAlbumItemLongClickListener(AlbumItemLongClickListener albumItemLongClickListener) {
        this.albumItemLongClickListener = albumItemLongClickListener;
    }

    public void setOnAlbumBtnClickListener(AlbumBtnClickListener albumBtnClickListener) {
        this.albumBtnClickListener = albumBtnClickListener;
    }

}
```

Comment: yeah i will implement and check this..I think in your edited code need to add constraintlayout field in view holder

Comment: @Deva Yes I did not add the filter you had in your `SoungAdapter`. I only added what you asked for, you can add the rest. Let me know

Comment: Thank you bro.. Ok i will try whenever iam free .. Thanks for your time and help.. :) Seems it will work ..

Comment: @Deva no problem, let me know if you have any issues:)